# 68000 - How to I check if value in data register is odd using ANDI?

Tags: 68000

This is my code i have: I want to see whether the value in D1 is odd. If so i want to perform some operation. Can someone help me with this?

It would be nice if somone could show me an example of how to use it.

Comment: AND with the value 1. If the result is 1, then it's odd.

Comment: Could you please show me of how the ANDI instruction will be?

Comment: http://68k.hax.com/AND

Comment: [ANDI.W](http://68k.hax.com/ANDI) #1,D0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a bit-wise `AND` of your input and a constant (immediate) value where only bit 0 is set, the result will be either 0 or 1, depending on the value of bit 1 in the input.

So:

```
check_odd:
    andi.b #1,d0
    beq.s  .even    ; If the result was zero, the Z flag is set, and beq jumps.
.odd:
    ; We end up here if the value was odd.
    bra.s  .done
.even:
    ; We end up here if the value was even.
.done:
```

Answer (score 0):

`andi.b #1,d1` would trash previous value of d1; therefore shorter command `lsr.w #1,d1` is possible. You then `bcs label` if the number is odd, `bcc label` otherwise.

Another option is to use `btst.l #0,d1`, which won't destroy contents of d1. Then `beq label` if number is even or `bne label` if odd.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only checking a single bit (as in this case) then you can also use the bit test instruction

```
btst #0, d0
beq  even
```

will branch to the label 'even' if bit 0 is not set.

Not sure if this offers any computational performance benefits, but may help with readability of code.